# Loading texturecube using DirectXTK DDSTextureLoader

Tags: directx

I've been trying to implement a skybox for some time now and there's probably only a tiny problem left to solve. When I load a texture using DirectXTK's CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx with a TEXTURECUBE flag, the resulting shader resource has its view dimension set to Texture2D and not TextureCube, which means I can't treat it as a TextureCube in HLSL. Also the file I'm loading contains all six faces. Here's the code where the texture is loaded:

```
// Loading the texture﻿
HRESULT hr = DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx(device, filename, 0, D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE, D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE, 
    0, D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE, false, &texture, &mSkyboxSRV);
```

This is the error message being output by DirectX:

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: The Shader Resource View dimension declared in the shader code (TEXTURECUBE) does not match the view type bound to slot 0 of the Pixel Shader unit (TEXTURE2D).  This mismatch is invalid if the shader actually uses the view (e.g. it is not skipped due to shader code branching). [ EXECUTION ERROR #354: DEVICE_DRAW_VIEW_DIMENSION_MISMATCH]

I've also tried this:

```
ID3D11Texture2D* texture = nullptr;

HRESULT hr = DirectX::CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx(device, filename, 0, D3D11_USAGE_IMMUTABLE, D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE, 
0, D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE, false, (ID3D11Resource**)&texture, nullptr);

D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texDesc;
texture->GetDesc(&texDesc);

D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC srvDesc;

srvDesc.TextureCube.MipLevels = texDesc.MipLevels;
srvDesc.TextureCube.MostDetailedMip = 0;
srvDesc.Format = texDesc.Format;
srvDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURECUBE;

hr = device->CreateShaderResourceView(texture, &srvDesc, &mSkyboxSRV);
```

But that gives me an error message saying the texture's view dimension and the srv's view dimension are not the same:

D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11Device::CreateShaderResourceView: Resources created without D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE may not be treated as cubemap ShaderResourceViews. [ STATE_CREATION ERROR #126: CREATESHADERRESOURCEVIEW_INVALIDDESC]

Does anyone have any ideas on what to do? Any help is much appreciated!﻿﻿

Comment: Does the ``DDS`` you are using actually contain a cubemap or does it contain a texture 2D array? If you can share a link to the ``DDS``, I can take a look.

Comment: Note that one immediate problem here is that you shouldn't do the cast you did above in the second code block which is not safe for COM interfaces. You should use ``ID3D11Resource*`` and then use ``QueryInterface`` to convert to a ``ID3D11Texture2D*``.  [ComPtr](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/ComPtr) makes this a lot easier. See [the DirectXTK wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader#debugging-texture-loading) for a more complete code sample that can also help in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: The [DDSTextureLoader](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/blob/master/Src/DDSTextureLoader.cpp) also ignores the ``D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE`` flag as a parameter. I should probably not clear it out in the case of a 2D texture array ``DDS`` if it has a multiple of 6 array entries... Otherwise it's not valid or it's set anyhow if the ``DDS`` is actually a cube map.

Answer (score 1):

When trying to debug failing `DDS` loads, you should do the following:

- Verify the DDS contains what you think it should. See [DDSDump.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wiki/Microsoft/DirectXTex/ddsdump.cpp) as a useful first-step.
- If you are getting a `SUCCESS` HRESULT back from the loader, then use the `ID3D11Resource**` parameter and use the code on the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/DDSTextureLoader) to validate it is what you think it should be.
- Otherwise, step into the DDSTextureLoader code line-by-line to see where it is failing...

**UPDATE**: As of the August 2018 release of *DirectX Tool Kit*, if you call `CreateDDSTextureFromFileEx` with the `D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE` flag in the parameters -and- the `DDS` contains a 2D texture array with a multiple of six entries, then I'll pass it along as if it's a cubemap.

See [this commit](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/commit/4b8a67578d0e7bf1424d39d05e03024ec1bdf7d9)

Comment: Again, thanks Chuck. It was the file lacking a header.